# Does Yodlee test users are active?

Tags: yodlee

I try to implement simple flow using Yodlee API and have a feeling that the test users are not active.

1. When I register a new account (/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1) to one of the test users I dont get any error but I use wrong credentials - is that the way it should be?
2. When I try to perform a search for trasactions on that user I get results but all the accounts I register are with wrong credentials.. how come?

Does the test users are simple stubs that doesnt really regisster to account?
Does the test users simple returning default resaults for search?

Thanx,
Nir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register to developer.yodlee.com , you get 5 registered users and for each of those users a DAG site is pre added and hence you are able to search transctions for the user.

When you link a new account using `/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1` API , you get a response which inclueds the siteAccountID and the initial refresh status . After this you will have to check for the refresh status in a loop using  `/Refresh/getSiteRefreshInfo` API to get the final status and error code.(https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/getSiteRefreshInfo)
if the siteRefreshStatus returned is either

```
PARTIAL_COMPLETE
or
REFRESH_COMPLETED
and 
code = 0
```

then it means that you have successfully linked an account.